# Rails model change field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to change the `created_at` format in the model,so I write like this:

```
class Mem < ActiveRecord::Base
  def created_at
    DateTime.strptime(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') 
  end
end
```

But I got

```
stack level too deep
```

Then what should I do?thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you call the same method `create_at`, try:

```
def created_at
  DateTime.strptime(self[:created_at], '%d-%m-%Y') 
end
```

also you can try:

```
def created_at
   DateTime.strptime(super, '%d-%m-%Y') 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to access attribute value. This should work:

```
class Mem < ActiveRecord::Base
  def created_at
    DateTime.strptime(attributes['created_at'], '%d-%m-%Y') 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Rename** your method...

```
self.my_created_at
  ##Jul 05,2014
 created_at.strftime("%b %d,%Y") 
 ##OR July 5th, 2014
 ##created_at.to_date.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)
end
```

**and use it:-**

```
  <%=@user.my_created_at.strftime("%b %d,%Y") %> =>  Jul 05,2014

    <%= @user.my_created_at.to_date.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)%> => July 5th, 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

`def created_at
    DateTime.strptime(self.created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') 
end`